# How do you change apple iCal start time to actual start time instead of the next hour?

Tags: calendar, ical

I use iCal to track time on work for clients. When I create a new event it has always put in the next hour. For example, if I started working at 9:40, the new event would start at 10:00. I tried Terminal with:

`defaults write com.apple.iCal 'Default duration in minutes for new event' 1`

That just makes the start time 10:01.

Comment: so you want the Start time to be `current time` ?

Comment: That will not set the Start time to current time